# Getting type mismatch on varargs in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Here is my simple situation in code

```
fun receiveDogs(vararg dog: Dog){
    processDogs(dog)
    ... //more cool stuff
}

fun processDogs(vararg dog: Dog){
  .....//cool stuff
}
```

When I do this the calling of `processDogs(dog)` causes a compilation error of

> Type mismatch.
>
> Required: Dog
>
> Found: Array`<out Dog>`

Now understand that both of my functions want a vararg. Is there a simple way to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh... you need to do

```
processDogs(*dog)
```

You need to spread the array into vararg again.

Answer (score 2):

According to [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs):

> Inside a function a vararg-parameter of type T is visible as an array of T

So your function `processDogs` needs to take dogs parameter as `Array<out T>` or you could use spread operator `*` on the array to pass it in vararg function.

```
fun processDogs(dogs: Array<Dog>)
```

or

```
processDogs(*dog)
```

as mentioned above.
Both compiles and works fine

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. +1